# Set dropdown value equal to hidden field

Tags: javascript

I have an html5 page where I want to set the value of a dropdown menu based on a hidden field but its not working.

```
function checkPayAdd() { 
var i;
var PayAddOption =document.querySelectorAll('input[name="PayAddOption"]');

for ( i = 0;  i < PayAddOption.length; i++) {

if (PayAddOption[i].checked == true) {

switch(i)
{
  case 0:
  document.getElementById("BillingAddress1").value = document.getElementById("Contact_Address1").value;      
  document.getElementById("BillingAddress2").value = document.getElementById("Contact_Address2").value;
  document.getElementById("BillingCity").value = document.getElementById("Contact_City").value;
  document.getElementById("BillingProv").selectedIndex = document.getElementById("First_Corp_Director_Prov").value;      
  document.getElementById("BillingPostalCode").value = document.getElementById("Contact_Postal").value; 
  document.getElementById("BillingCountry").selectedIndex = document.getElementById("First_Corp_Director_Country").value;       
  break
```

I set the values of the hidden field in the same format as those in the drop downs - ie. Province value in hidden field is: "AL" which should then set the Billing.Prov dropdown value to the same. These are the hidden fields

```
<input type="hidden" name="First_Corp_Director_Province"  id="First_Corp_Director_Province" value="AL">

        <input type="hidden" name="First_Corp_Director_Country" id="First_Corp_Director_Country" value="US">

<select name="BillingProv" id="BillingProv" class="form-control">
            <option value="">select State or Province (Canada/US Only)</option>
            <option value="ZZ">Outside US or Canada</option>
            <optgroup label="United States">
              <option id="USA-AL" value="AL">Alabama (AL)</option>
              <option id="USA-AK" value="AK">Alaska (AK)</option>
              <option id="USA-AZ" value="AZ">Arizona (AZ)</option>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 errors here

1. You should be assigning to the **value** of the select element instead of **selectedIndex**.
2. The id of hidden field is wrong. Should be **First_Corp_Director_Province** instead of
   **First_Corp_Director_Prov**.

so the replace your 4th line of switch case 0 with

```
document.getElementById("BillingProv").value = document.getElementById("First_Corp_Director_Province").value;
```

and 6th line with

```
document.getElementById("BillingCountry").value = document.getElementById("First_Corp_Director_Country").value;
```

Comment: It might be possible that the selected index is required for the country (there are like 200 countries) and adding them all in code is a bit more tedious than a loop with 200 numbers which checks availability.

Comment: Here Jeff has only the value stored in the hidden field, not the index. To use selectedIndex he needs have the index. For that either he needs to get the index from whole array(if available) or needs create the array from option which is again some extra code. Providing the value to value field lets the select element work on it.